# How can I find a space character in an <input> using CSS3 selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

My way: [code](http://www.jsfiddle.net/fv6fD/)

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> type a space and press Submit
</form>

$('form').submit(function(){
    if($('input').val() == ' ') {
        alert($('input').val().length);
    }
   return false;    
});
```

But I'd like to solve this problem using CSS3 selectors like `$('input[value*=" "]')`

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: So spaces are not allowed in the field at all? Or is it values that are *just* spaces that aren't allowed?

Comment: @Algorithm no I mean why you want to do this with selector expressions instead of just straightforward code?

Comment: @lonesomeday only a few fields. I can filter it using RegExp, but I'd like to know whether it is possible to use CSS3 selectors

Comment: You already solved it. `[value*=" "]` is a valid CSS3 attribute selector.

Comment: @elusive This way doesn't work

Comment: @Algorithm: Can you show us the code you used to test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking to use CSS3 selector through jquery then `$(':input[value*=" "]')` should do it.

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/cruRd/

If you want to create an actual CSS3 rule in your stylesheet then `input[value*=' ']{..}` will work, but only for values in the actual attribute (*in the source code*) and not the value as modified inside the browser..

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/VzE9T/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot manipulate data with CSS; it's a formatting language. You don't have variables or functions which help you find something in a string. Use JS instead.

Comment: I think he means that he wants to use CSS3-style jQuery selectors (for some reason)

Comment: Oh, didn't get the question the first time :)